# jQuery added form works after refresh

Tags: jquery, html

i have image with it attached form! and when i change some value in form, then it automatically .post() values to other file and updates DB! i also have option to add new image and then it append image and new form for that (new-)image, but form does not .post() values for that new image until i have refreshed the page.... HTML IS 100% CORRECT

```
var http_adr = "http://192.168.1.200/dev/";

function addPictures(what, where){
    AIM.start(what,{
        AppendData:{
            'parent':where
        },

        beforeComplete:function(){
        },

        onComplete:function(returnData){
            var jdata=$.parseJSON(returnData);
            for (var i=0; i<jdata.filename.length; i++){
                var html_var = '<div class="image_wrapper"><div class=""><img src="../../module/catalog/product_img/'+where+'/'+jdata.filename[i]+'_small.jpg" /></div><div class="details_div">';

                var html_var2 = '';

                for (var n=0; n<jdata.detail_table[i].length; n++){
                    html_var2 = html_var2 + '<form name="' + jdata.pdid[i] + '">' + jdata.detail_table[i][n] + '<input name="price" value="0.00" /><input name="stock" value="0" /></form>';
                }

                var html_done = html_var + html_var2 + '</div></div>';
                $('.box:visible').append($(html_done).hide().fadeIn(1500));
            }
        },

        UPtarget:http_adr+'plugins/upload/upload.php'
        });
    }

    var iloc = '../../module/catalog/_i.php';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input').change(function() {
            var pdid = $(this).parent('form').attr("name");
            $.post(
                iloc,
                $(this).serialize() + '&pdid=' + pdid + '&a=edit_detail',
                function(data) {
                }
            );
        })
    })
```

Comment: I suspect that $(document).ready my cause that problem! because, (just-) added form is added AFTER document is "ready".. that is my noob suspicion!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('body').on("change", "input", function() {
```

instead of

```
$('input').change(function() {
```

so when you retrieve a new input from ajax the event bubbles up and be catched and handled.

**UPDATE**:
Also try changing your following line:

```
$('.box:visible').append($(html_done).hide().fadeIn(1500));
```

for this one:

```
$('.box:visible').hide().append(html_done).fadeIn(1500);
```

because you were hiding and fadeing in an html wasn't attached to DOM yet.

Comment: Could you have ment the .live function? Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Comment: @Stefan , yes, but .live() is deprecated on jQuery 1.7 and .on() should be used instead, if OP is using jquery < 1.7 he should use .live() instead of .on() . Thanks for raising attention to that point!.

Comment: I see. Thanks for this information, I just wanted to use live everywhere in my code. Do you happen to know, if .on works with jquery ui, so elements e.g a button is styled with jquery-ui even if it is atteched / modified later on?

Comment: how :P, I'm only able to attech events to the element